# Visual studio 2013 broken symbols with nested struct template parameter

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, debug-symbols

```
template <class T> struct SomeTemplateClass {
    SomeTemplateClass() {}
};

struct Not_Nested {};

int main() {

    struct Nested {};

    SomeTemplateClass<Not_Nested> a;
    SomeTemplateClass<Nested> b;
}
```

When I run this program from visual studio, I get the following symbols:

- `SomeTemplateClass<Not_Nested>::SomeTemplateClass<Not_Nested>` for a
- `?? ::XZ::QAE::SomeTemplateClass<,ain>::SomeTemplateClass<,ain>` for b

Is this a bug? Is there a workaround ?

I have been using [SymFromAddr](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681323(v=vs.85).aspx), [SymInitialize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681351(v=vs.85).aspx) and [SymSetOptions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681366(v=vs.85).aspx) in one project, and managed to retrieve some function names from function pointers.

Could symbols be messed up because of this?

Comment: What about creating a new project and taking a shot?

Comment: @EricZ I already made a brand new project to test this code.

Comment: Still fail? It runs fine on my vc 2012 which I currently have.